# Ansible Roles : What content should I wtrite in `site.yml` and `webservers.yml`?

Tags: ansible-2.x

There is an example for role directory structure in the docs(http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure)

> Example project structure:

```
site.yml
webservers.yml
fooservers.yml
roles/
   common/
     tasks/
     handlers/
     files/
     templates/
     vars/
     defaults/
     meta/
   webservers/
     tasks/
     defaults/
     meta/
```

**Question：**
What content should I write in `site.yml` and `webservers.yml`?

for example:

Documentation says(http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles),

> The classic (original) way to use roles is via the roles: option for a given play:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> - hosts: webservers
>   roles:
>      - common
>      - webservers
> ```

Which file can I put the above content in?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation examples, you would have:

webservers.yml:

```
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
     - common
     - webservers
```

fooservers.yml:

```
- hosts: fooservers
  roles:
     - common
  tasks:
     - shell: /usr/bin/foo.sh
```

site.yml:

```
- include: webservers.yml
- include: fooservers.yml
```